# Does Corda really require a notary to achieve uniqueness consensus?

Tags: corda, consensus

The Corda [introduction to consensus](https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/key-concepts-consensus.html) says "uniqueness consensus is provided by notaries."

Are we saying that without a notary that it would be possible for A to convince B to commit a transaction to its ledger involving a state X as an input and at the same time, or later, convince C to commit a *different* transaction involving X to its ledger?

In this situation the ledger of A would be inconsistent with that of C (or B or both depending on what transaction, if any, it chooses to commit) and A would have created a situation that is inconsistent now and can never become consistent between A, B and C.

Presumably, the Corda framework tries to prevent this kind of thing as far as possible, so is this all about honesty? I.e. we're talking about the situation where A completely subverts its own infrastructure, i.e. doesn't use Corda as intended, and lies in all the messages it sends other parties?

---

**Update:** this question was initially asked due to my mistaken belief that notaries were an optional element of a Corda system. They are not, but their involvement may be optional for particular transactions, e.g. ones that involve no input states (and therefore by their nature have no double-spend issue).

The important thing that @joel makes clear in his answer is that the double-spend issue can also be a problem even if all parties trust each other, i.e. no malicious behavior is expected.

Once a party in Corda determines that validity consensus has been reached for a transaction it can immediately commit the transaction to its own ledger, i.e. it does not first try to reach some kind of additional BFT style consensus with the other parties that they can and will definitely commit the transaction to their respective ledgers as well.

So in the above scenario A could honestly/mistakenly propose two different transactions to B and C. B and C would both reach validity consensus on their respective transactions and commit them to their own ledgers with A only being confronted with the double-spend issue when it afterwards tried to commit the second of the two transactions to its own ledger.

The notary avoids such situations (whether the result of malicious intent or not).

Comment: Hmm.. probably pressed post too quickly there. On checking the suggested linked questions I see that @joel from R3 has already answered similar questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817684/245602) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329391/245602)). In particular the second one (at the end) provides reasons why one might chose not to use a notary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons you need a notary:

- **Malicious nodes**: A node purposefully extracts a consumed state from its vault, consumes it in another transaction, and sends the transaction to a counterparty who didn't see the original transaction
- **Race conditions**: Two nodes simultaneously propose transactions consuming the same state

Comment: Can you give a race condition example? It's clear that two parties can _propose_ two different transactions that involve the same input state but is it really possible for both such proposals to really reach the point where they can both be committed to the ledgers of all relevant parties? I.e. surely during the process of agreeing to sign the proposed transaction at least one party, even without a notary, will become aware of the issue and refuse to continue with the process that would result in the _proposal_ becoming a _committed_ transaction?

Comment: The nodes don't check whether they're consuming the same state in two flows at once. So a node could be involved in two separate flows that sign transactions consuming the same state, and they'd only realise at the point of trying to store the second state in their vault. Unfortunately, PartyA may store Tx1 first, while PartyB stores Tx2 first, leading to inconsistent ledgers.

Comment: This question (and my [followup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49295368/245602)) were based on a misunderstanding about the optionality of notaries. I'm now clear on this, thanks for your help getting there :) I've updated my question to reflect this (and deleted my followup question).