# Why does corda needs consensus, since corda being permissioned blockchain

Tags: corda

I am working on a solution which supposed to handle high traffic ie looking for the highest tps configuration Corda could provide, Since consensus could be costly I was thinking to go for a configuration where no consensus needed.

Comment: AFAIK there always must be a consensus. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260900/2402281).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in a permissioned network, double-spend attacks are possible. The notary also serves as the timestamping authority.

As of Corda 4, there is no way to disable consensus. Every transaction requires a notary, and every transaction with inputs and/or a timestamp requires a signature from this notary.

Comment: So the consensus used to make agreement between multiple notary clusters, in that case single notary network not really needed any consensus, please advise.

Comment: Consensus isn't about agreement between different notary clusters. It's about agreement between nodes about what transactions are valid (including that that they don't represent double-spends).